# How to interpret the value of Cluster Centers in k means

Tags: python

I use the intended code to output the results of the clustering. What does this value mean in "Cluster Centers", and how should I interpret this data?

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4).fit(df)
print("Number of clusters: ", kmeans.n_clusters)
print("-"*70)
print("Cluster Centers: ", '\n', kmeans.cluster_centers_)
Number of clusters:  4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster Centers:  
 [[4.10000000e+02 9.92833333e+03 3.42200000e+03 3.73333333e+00
  2.32433333e+03 1.36733333e+03 1.31600000e+03 5.16666667e+01
  9.57000000e+02]
 [4.55000000e+01 3.41650000e+03 1.42100000e+04 3.70000000e+00
  5.95000000e+02 3.60000000e+02 3.46500000e+02 1.35000000e+01
  2.34500000e+02]
 [3.41666667e+01 1.14600000e+03 3.33358333e+03 3.69166667e+00
  7.02500000e+02 4.14583333e+02 3.99166667e+02 1.53333333e+01
  2.87916667e+02]
 [5.14000000e+02 2.48310000e+04 5.78750000e+03 3.75000000e+00
  1.75350000e+03 1.05200000e+03 1.01200000e+03 3.95000000e+01
  7.02000000e+02]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have four clusters, and the given vectors ar the centers of those clusters.
So, for a new point, you can check which centroid is the closest and you can determine the new point cluster accordingly.

For example, for the following four clusters above the X represent its centroids for the clusters and a new point can be classified accordingly.

Also, you can check for yourself measurement on the clusters. you can check here:  [Silhouette - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering))
[image: cluster_centroids]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, is it good for this value to approach 1? I have 19 samples and 9 eigenvalues, does this mean they are 9 eigenvalues?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the full dataset plot.

Comment: if it help your initial question, please accept the answer

Comment: @TSAIYI-FAN: There are no eigenvalues involved in KMeans. KMeans is simply a vector quantization of your dataset. See [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code asked to find four clusters using the KMeans algorithm. See [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). As expected, you obtain 4 clusters. Based on the `kmeans.cluster_centers_`, we can tell that your space is 9-dimensional (9 coordinates for each point), because the cluster centroids are 9-dimensional.

The centroids are the means of all points within a cluster. [This doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) is a good introduction for getting an intuitive understanding of the k-means algorithm.